# Nested form renders unknown attribute error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, nested, parameters

I am using gem nested form https://github.com/ryanb/nested_form in order to create a Flat with multiple pictures. 
The Flat model has many pictures. 
the form looks like that :

```
<%= simple_nested_form_for @flat do |f| %>
  <%= f.error_notification %>

  <div class="form-inputs">
    <%= f.input :name %>
    <%= f.fields_for :pictures do |pictures_form| %>
      <%= pictures_form.file_field :image %>
      <%= pictures_form.link_to_remove ('<i class="fa fa-trash"></i>').html_safe %>
    <% end %>
     <%= f.link_to_add ('<i class="fa fa-plus"></i>').html_safe, :pictures %>
  </div>
  <div class="form-actions">
    <%= f.button :submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

My controller create action :

```
  def create
    @flat = Flat.new(flat_params)
    authorize @flat
    @flat.user = current_user
    @flat.pictures.build

    if @flat.save
      redirect_to flat_path(@flat), notice: 'Flat was successfully created.'
    else
      render :new
    end
  end
```

and my flat_params :

```
 def flat_params
      params.require(:flat).permit(:name, pictures_attributes: [:id, :image, :_destroy])
    end
```

I always get the following error :
unknown attribute 'image' for Picture.

I used the gem paperclip for image upload Here's how my table picture looks in my schema :

```
create_table "pictures", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.datetime "created_at",         null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",         null: false
    t.string   "image_file_name"
    t.string   "image_content_type"
    t.integer  "image_file_size"
    t.datetime "image_updated_at"
    t.integer  "flat_id"
  end
```

What is the problem ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why are you *building* in the `create` method? This is where you *save* only:

```
  def new
    @flat = Flat.new
    @flat.pictures.build #-> pictures.build should be in the new method only
  end

  def create
    @flat = Flat.new flat_params
    @flat.user = current_user

    authorize @flat

    if @flat.save
      redirect_to @flat, notice: 'Flat was successfully created.'
    else
      render :new
    end
  end
```

Other than the above (`pictures.build`), your code looks good.

The other issue you *may* have is that you've not included the Paperclip reference in your `Picture` model. You'll need to have the following:

```
#app/models/picture.rb
class Picture < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_attached_file :image #-> + any styling options etc
end
```

From the code you've provided, that's what I can give.